# How to cross-reference to labels from a .tex file that isn't compiled?

Tags: cross-referencing

I'm working on a big project consisting of many small sections. I write the different sections in separate `.tex` files and then use the `import` package to compile them in the main document. When working on the project I only compile the current file so that I don't have to scroll through the entire project. It is also necessary that I can download pdf files of certain sections rather than the entire project. There lies my problem: I frequently cross-reference back to parts in earlier sections using `\label{}` and `\ref{}`. However, latex doesn't recognize the labels unless I compile the file where they are located. Therefore the cross-references don't work when I only compile the current section.

Is there any way around this problem, i.e. is there a way to cross-reference to labels without compiling the file in which they are located?

Comment: no, you need the aux-file of the files with the label definition, so you have to compile them once.

Comment: I'm not familiar with aux-files. Also, I tried to compile the entire document but it didn't make any difference.